# React dom refreshed too slow

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I set my vscode make auto-save every 1sec.

So, when I edit code, react should be refreshed every time and I don't need to press f5 for refresh window.

But, like picture below, it didn't refreshed and send me an error. In my vscode, I wrote setFiltered. But error said I wrote only setF.

[image]

This happens frequently and irritate me.
Somebody help please...

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference error - you have not declared "setF" in your code.

Check your code and read the whole message - on line 24 you wrote "setF" and "setF" is not defined - very simple.

Comment: No I wrote setFiltered but it didn't rendered correctly. The problem is React rendered too slow